# PIC32 and MPLAB Harmony, USART driver

Tags: pic, c, uart, microchip, mplabx

I am trying to output some ADC readings from a potentiometer over USART using the PIC32MX220F032B. I have the hardware all setup and working and i've set up a new project using MPLAB harmony and have the PIC picking up values from a potentiometer using the ADC module. I've set up the USART module too and I am able to output single bytes at a time using Harmony's DRV USART driver ByteWrite function however I have been struggling for hours to try convert the integer ADC readings into an ASCII representation that I can send to Putty, my terminal program. The problem is such that the harmony driver function DRV_USART0_WriteByte(argument); takes a uint8_t as argument.

I tried writing the following functions to convert each decimal to a uint8_t and transmit using the driver write function:

```
void intToByte(int input){
    int j    = 0;
    int size = numPlaces(input);

    while(j<size){
        appData.buffer = input % 10;  // remainder of division with 10 gets the last digit
        input /= 10;                  // dividing by ten chops off the last digit.
        DRV_USART0_WriteByte(appData.buffer);
        j++;
    } 
}


int numPlaces (int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return floor (log10l(abs(n)))+ 1;
}
```

unfortunately I'm just getting different non sensical ASCII characters in my serial terminal program.

I was wondering if there are any PIC32 experts who have worked with Harmony who might be able to tell me how they approach printing integers using `DRV_USART0_WriteByte()`.

Comment: 'appData.buffer = input % 10;' puts the valu of that digit into your buffer, not the ASCII character which represents that digit. Try 'appData.buffer = '0' + input % 10;' instead.

Comment: Even better would be to just use snprintf() though.